# Derivation of Ideal gas law from kinetic theory

Tags: ideal-gas

From Wikipedia:

[image]

I understand everything up to here:
$$|∆p| = 2mvN'= \frac{Nt_1Smv^2}{6V}$$

It's where they mention that:
$$F = \frac{|∆p|}{t_2}$$

and use it to simplify the former equation to obtain the desired result.

I have deliberately subscripted the two $t$'s differently to emphasize that I don't think they are equivalent. $t_1$ refers to to the time taken for all the particles to collide with the wall. Whereas $t_2$ should be the time taken for the particles to be in contact with the wall. An example I relate this to would be throwing a ball at a wall. When considering the force, given by $F = \frac{∆mv}{t}$, I wouldn't consider the time taken for the ball to reach the wall. The wikipedia definition however seems to have considered the two $t$'s to be equal. The only explanation I could come up with was that one of the assumptions — of an ideal gas in this context — must be that the time of collision is assumed negligible compared to the time elapsed between collisions.

Can someone help me verify my understanding?

Comment: Please, always explain the meaning of acronyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $t$ is the same in both cases.

Since the theory here assumes the wall is undergoing *constant* pressure and therefore constant force (**this** is where it deviates from your example of the time it takes for a thrown ball to reach a wall), you assume the wall is always undergoing the exact same number of collisions.

Thus if there are $N$ particles that take $t$ seconds to all hit the wall, and each collision takes $t_2$ seconds, there's $\frac{Nt_2}{t}$ collisions at any given time.

If each collision results in a force of $F_i = \frac{\Delta p}{t_2}\cdot\frac{1}{N}$, then the total force on the wall at any given time is $F_{tot} = \frac{Nt_2}{t} \cdot \frac{\Delta p}{t_2N} = \frac{\Delta p}{t}$.

And therefore the value of $t_2$ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

For the equation involving $t_1$ the author is calculating how *many* particles are hitting the wall. For this you should have a picture like this in mind:

[image]

The picture shows the flux of particles as if it's a river, but it's still a useful mental picture.
The volume of the particles of particles that have collided in timestep $\Delta t$ is approximately $S\Delta t$. The number of particles that collided in that timestep is then approximately

$$N'=\rho V'=\frac{N}{V}V'=\frac{NS\Delta t}{V}$$

For the second equation the author imagines how much force these particles impart on the wall. You can imagine summing up all the momenta that are imparted on the wall within timestep $\Delta t$ and then dividing this expression by the time interval to get an average force:

$$F_{avg}=\frac 1{\Delta t}\sum_i\Delta p_i=\frac{N'mv}{\Delta t}$$

You can then take the limit as $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$, because, very nicely, this expression does not depend on time.